# docker mechanism that allow container to not intialize postgres server while container starts?

Tags: postgresql, docker

i try to understand why,
by executing this command :

```
docker run --rm -it postgres bash
```

container starts well, gives me a bash prompt, without intializing
a postgres server.

In fact, when i only execute this :

```
docker run --rm -it postgres
```

container tries to intialize a postgres server and failed
because a non provided '-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD' sequence
which is absolutly normal.

But the question is :
what is the mechanism in 'docker' or 'in the official postgres image'
that tell container to :

- not initialize a postgres server when an argument is provided
  at the end of 'docker run --rm -it postgres' sequence
  (like bash or psql..)
- DO initialize a postgres server when NO argument is provided
  (docker run --rm -it postgres)

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`postgres` image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/75d0c1135e1cfd183bf7ee0970b7031986b0710d/15/bullseye/Dockerfile) is set up as

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["postgres"]
```

When an image has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, [the command part is passed as additional parameters to the entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  If you `docker run postgres bash`, the `bash` command overrides the command part but leaves the entrypoint intact.

This *entrypoint wrapper script* setup is a common and useful technique.  The script can do anything it needs to do to make the container ready to use, and then end with the shell command `exec "$@"` to run the command it got passed as arguments.  Typical uses for this include dynamically setting environment variables, populating mounted volumes, and (for application containers more than database containers) waiting for a database or other container dependency to be ready.

In the particular case of the `postgres` image, its [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/75d0c1135e1cfd183bf7ee0970b7031986b0710d/15/bullseye/docker-entrypoint.sh) does (simplified):

```bash
if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ] && ! _pg_want_help "$@"; then
    docker_setup_env
    docker_create_db_directories
    if [ -z "$DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS" ]; then
        docker_init_database_dir
        docker_setup_db
        docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
    fi
fi
exec "$@"
```

Since the entrypoint script is just a shell script and it does have the command as positional parameters, it can make decisions based on what the command actually is.  In this case, `if [ "$1" = 'postgres' ]` – if the main container command is to run the PostgreSQL server – then do the first-time initialization, otherwise don't.

Comment: wonderful exhaustiv response. thanks